# Apache - HTTPS: Show content of HTTP

Tags: apache-2.2, http, https

I have a Facebook app on my server and I need to run it both at http and at https. Now I have two different folders on my server: httpdocs and httpsdocs. How could I point now from the httpsdocs folder to the "normal" httpdocs folder that contains the files/page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest answer is to change the `DocumentRoot` of the SSL virtual host to the same folder as the non-SSL virtual host.  In other words, change `httpsdocs` to `httpdocs` in the configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, you can point both your HTTP and HTTPS vhosts to the same directory - if there are no different files, there is not reason to keep two identical directories.

And, if you really need two separate directories, you can make symbolic links to keep the identical content in sync:

```
ln -s /var/www/httpdocs/somefileordirectory /var/www/httpsdocs/
```

You can see `man ln` for more information.